# FOSUserBundle and FOSFacebookBundle : userManager->updateUser() : "unknown error" (it is a doctrine error)

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

**FOSUserBundle** works good for the project I'm working on. But I'm trying to embed **FOSFacebookBundle** and make it work with **FOSUserBundle**.

Within this purpose I've built my own *`Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User.php`* to add some fields that I'd like to store from Facebook in addition to what provides the UserBundle. The
code of this class has been debugged and works (well... that's what I thought ! see below).

What doesn't work is (in my *`Acme\MyBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider.php`*, inside the *loadUserByUsername()*) this line :

```
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
```

The *`Acme\MyBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider.php`* is the same as the documentation ([read it here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/README.md))

The following element is the output of `print_r($user);` just before the
execution of `$this->userManager->updateUser($user);` :

```
Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User Object
(
    [id:protected] =>
    [facebookID:protected] => 847000001
    [first_name:protected] => Peter
    [middle_name:protected] =>
    [last_name:protected] => Parker
    [fullname:protected] => Peter Parker
    [locale:protected] => en_US
    [timezone:protected] => 2
    [updated_time:protected] => 2011-10-27T17:13:24+0000
    [birthday:protected] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 1961-07-01 10:31:53
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
        )
    [languages:protected] => Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object
        (
        [_elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array
            (
        [0] => Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage Object
            (
            [facebookID:Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage:private] => 113051505375958
            [name:Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage:private] => Italien
            )
        [1] => Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage Object
            (
            [facebookID:Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage:private] => 112264595467201
            [name:Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage:private] => FranÃÂ§ais
            )
        [2] => Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage Object
            (
            [facebookID:Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage:private] => 103803232991647
            [name:Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage:private] => English
            )
        )
    )
    [usernameFB:protected] => spiderman
    [username:protected] => Peter Parker
    [usernameCanonical:protected] =>
    [email:protected] => peterparker@marvel.com
    [emailCanonical:protected] =>
    [enabled:protected] => 1
    [algorithm:protected] =>
    [salt:protected] =>
    [password:protected] =>
    [plainPassword:protected] =>
    [lastLogin:protected] =>
    [confirmationToken:protected] => 540grdgfg343004g8g0skg0wg408k
    [passwordRequestedAt:protected] =>
    [groups:protected] =>
    [locked:protected] =>
    [expired:protected] =>
    [expiresAt:protected] =>
    [roles:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => ROLE_FACEBOOK
        )

    [credentialsExpired:protected] =>
    [credentialsExpireAt:protected] =>
)
```

The message error is **"UNKNOWN ERROR"**. So I decided to go to look Where this message is sent in the Bundle. And I've found that it was set in an Exception. I decided to output the Exception Message.

So below the Exception message:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User#languages' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage@000000004a9e2dfa0000000001482b74.
>   Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist
>   operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity
>   causes the problem implement
>   'Acme\MyBundle\Entity\SpokenLanguage#__toString()' to get a clue.

So I guess I have not well-coded the Doctrine Annotations of my User class and the problem is the ManyToMany() association mapping.

Here the Annotations of the field $languages in my *`Acme\MyBundle\Entity\User.php`*:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SpokenLanguage")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_spokenlanguage",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="spokenlanguage_id", referencedColumnName="facebookID")}
 *      )
 */
protected $languages;
```

Do you guys have anything in mind how to solve the problem? 
I'm thinking about a CASCADING Problem.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: OKAY! I've solved this... Finally you have to add the parameter `cascade={'persist','remove','merge'}` to the Annotation ManyToMany.
Like this:
`@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SpokenLanguage", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})`

Comment: please post your comment as an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 2):

OKAY! I've solved this finally!

You have to add the parameter `cascade={'persist','remove','merge'}` to the Annotation ManyToMany.

Like this:

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SpokenLanguage", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
```